# Blackberry sqlite boolean type

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

Can anybody tell me does BlackBerry `Sqlite` supports Boolean type or not?

```
 statement = database.createStatement("CREATE TABLE DEPT(Code TEXT,Description TEXT, Status Boolean)" );
```

Is that possible in blackberry `sqlite`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if on Blackberry there is a standard or customized version of SQLite.

If it is a standard one, according to SQLite documentation (see: [here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)) it does not support boolean type, you have to use 0 and 1.

Comment: i like this..bye the way blackberry doesn't have any special sqlite.only standard one have to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
statement = database.createStatement("CREATE TABLE DEPT(Code TEXT,Description TEXT, Status INTEGER)" );
```

and make it `NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)`

Boolean is not supported...